# 直前のページ情報を取得し反映させたい。

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5

hoge.com/hogeに表示される内容を直前のページまたは動的に何らかの方法で情報を取得し変更したい。

例
hoge.com/hoge/1
hoge.com/hoge/2
hoge.com/hoge/3
hoge.com/hoge/4

↓へアクセス

hoge.com/hoge

↓変更

hoge.com/hogeの表示内容を直前のページから取得し表示。

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Headerに直前のページのURLがRefererとして含まれていると思います。（セキュリティ上の配慮からRefererを空白にするなどの対処をしているサイトもありますが、自分のサイトであれば、Refererの情報を含むHeaderにできるはずです）

hoge.com/hoge　にアクセスされた際、HTML HeaderからRefererの情報(直前のページのURL)を収集し、そこにアクセスして情報収集したものをページに反映する事は可能だと思います。

サーバ側で特定のURLにアクセスされたことを検出して、対処する必要がありますから、ちょっと複雑になるとは思いますが。

＝＝
具体的な必要機能が判らないので、すごくざっくりとした回答ですが、Refererの情報が使いやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

いろいろな方法があります。

### クライアントだけで完結するもの

- 遷移前のページで cookie をセットし、遷移後のページで cookie を読んでコンテンツを変更する
- 同、cookie の代わりに localStorage を使う
- 同、cookie の代わりに sessionStorage を使う
- 同、cookie の代わりに Indexed Database を使う
- 遷移前のページから遷移後のページに行く際に、URLにquery parameterを付けて、遷移後のページで `location.search` を読んでコンテンツを変更する

### サーバの助けがいるもの

- HTTPの `Referer` ヘッダの値に従って生成するページの内容を変更する
- 遷移前のページからデータを付けてフォームを POST することでページ遷移する。サーバは POST されたデータに従って生成するページのコンテンツを変更する